# How to get url of a photo saved with ALAssetsLibrary?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm saving a photo with writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum of ALAssetsLibrary, In this method I have a compleion block that in objective c was:

```
 ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];  
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString]  
                            completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {  
                                if (error) {  
                                    NSLog(@"Save video fail:%@",error);  
                                } else {  
                                    NSLog(@"Save video succeed.");  
                                }  
                            }];
```

}

but when I show this in swift I get a object:

```
 typealias ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock = (NSURL!, NSError!) -> Void
```

And I only want get NSURL
In Swift I have this code for completion Block:

```
 var imageWriteCompletionBlock: ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock!

 self.completionBlock = {
            reason in println(reason)
        }
```

How can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
ALAssetsLibrary().writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(image.CGImage, 
         orientation: ALAssetOrientation.fromRaw(image.imageOrientation.toRaw())!,     
     completionBlock:{ (path:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                           println("\(path)")
                     })
```

regards,